# Getting QuercusView to work with SpringMVC

Tags: php, spring-mvc, quercus

I'm trying to implement SpringMVC + Quercus as described at http://blog.caucho.com/2009/04/14/using-php-as-a-spring-mvc-view-via-quercus/ .

So I setup Spring like this:

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ini-file</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/php.ini</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

### dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/themes/eyitope/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="php" value="application/php" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list> 
                <!-- used to handle all files with .php extension -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                    <property name="viewClass" value="com.caucho.spring.quercus.QuercusView"/>
                    <property name="order" value="1"/>
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/themes/php/"/>
                    <property name="suffix" value=".php"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- If a compatible view cannot be supplied by the
            ViewResolver chain, then the list of views specified through the DefaultViews property will be
            consulted.
        -->
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have a simple controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("account/*")
public class AccountController {

  public AccountController() {}

  @RequestMapping("signup")
    public String signupTestHandler() {
        return "signup";
    }

}
```

QuercusView looks like this:

```
package com.caucho.spring.quercus;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.caucho.quercus.*;
import com.caucho.quercus.env.*;
import com.caucho.quercus.module.*;
import com.caucho.quercus.page.*;

import com.caucho.util.L10N;
import com.caucho.vfs.*;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.*;

public class QuercusView
  extends AbstractUrlBasedView
{
  private static final L10N L = new L10N(QuercusView.class);

  private static final Logger log
    = Logger.getLogger(QuercusView.class.getName());

  protected QuercusContext _quercus;
  protected ServletContext _servletContext;

  public QuercusView()
  {
    super();
  }

        protected void initServletContext(ServletContext servletContext)
  {
    _servletContext = servletContext;

    checkServletAPIVersion();

    getQuercus().setPwd(new FilePath(_servletContext.getRealPath("/")));

    getQuercus().init();
  }

  protected void checkServletAPIVersion()
  {
    int major = _servletContext.getMajorVersion();
    int minor = _servletContext.getMinorVersion();

    if (major < 2 || major == 2 && minor < 4)
      throw new QuercusRuntimeException(L.l("Quercus requires Servlet API 2.4+."));
  }

  protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map model,
                                         HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception
  {
    Env env = null;
    WriteStream ws = null;

    try {
      Path path = getPath(request);

      QuercusPage page;

      try {
        page = getQuercus().parse(path);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // php/2001
        log.log(Level.FINER, ex.toString(), ex);

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);

        return;
      }

      StreamImpl out;

      try {
        out = new VfsStream(null, response.getOutputStream());
      }
      catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        WriterStreamImpl writer = new WriterStreamImpl();
        writer.setWriter(response.getWriter());

        out = writer;
      }

      ws = new WriteStream(out);

      ws.setNewlineString("\n");

      QuercusContext quercus = getQuercus();
      quercus.setServletContext(_servletContext);

      env = quercus.createEnv(page, ws, request, response);

      // retro... thanks, Spring
      for (Object entryObj : model.entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entryObj;
        env.setScriptGlobal((String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }

      try {
        env.start();

        env.setScriptGlobal("request", request);
        env.setScriptGlobal("response", response);
        env.setScriptGlobal("servletContext", _servletContext);

        StringValue prepend
          = quercus.getIniValue("auto_prepend_file").toStringValue(env);
        if (prepend.length() > 0) {
          Path prependPath = env.lookup(prepend);

          if (prependPath == null)
            env.error(L.l("auto_prepend_file '{0}' not found.", prepend));
          else {
            QuercusPage prependPage = getQuercus().parse(prependPath);
            prependPage.executeTop(env);
          }
        }

        env.executeTop();

        StringValue append
          = quercus.getIniValue("auto_append_file").toStringValue(env);
        if (append.length() > 0) {
          Path appendPath = env.lookup(append);

          if (appendPath == null)
            env.error(L.l("auto_append_file '{0}' not found.", append));
          else {
            QuercusPage appendPage = getQuercus().parse(appendPath);
            appendPage.executeTop(env);
          }
        }
        //   return;
      }
      catch (QuercusExitException e) {
        throw e;
      }
      catch (QuercusErrorException e) {
        throw e;
      }
      catch (QuercusLineRuntimeException e) {
        log.log(Level.FINE, e.toString(), e);

      //  return;
      }
      catch (QuercusValueException e) {
        log.log(Level.FINE, e.toString(), e);

        ws.println(e.toString());

      //  return;
      }
      catch (Throwable e) {
        if (response.isCommitted())
          e.printStackTrace(ws.getPrintWriter());

        ws = null;

        throw e;
      }
      finally {
        if (env != null)
          env.close();

        // don't want a flush for a thrown exception
        if (ws != null)
          ws.close();
      }
    }
    catch (QuercusDieException e) {
      // normal exit
      log.log(Level.FINE, e.toString(), e);
    }
    catch (QuercusExitException e) {
      // normal exit
      log.log(Level.FINER, e.toString(), e);
    }
    catch (QuercusErrorException e) {
      // error exit
      log.log(Level.FINE, e.toString(), e);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
      throw e;
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      throw new ServletException(e);
    }
  }

  Path getPath(HttpServletRequest req)
  {
    String scriptPath = getUrl();
    String pathInfo = QuercusRequestAdapter.getPagePathInfo(req);

    Path pwd = new FilePath(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    Path path = pwd.lookup(req.getRealPath(scriptPath));

    if (path.isFile())
      return path;

    // XXX: include

    String fullPath;
    if (pathInfo != null)
      fullPath = scriptPath + pathInfo;
    else
      fullPath = scriptPath;

    return pwd.lookup(req.getRealPath(fullPath));
  }

  /**
   * Returns the Quercus instance.
   */
  protected QuercusContext getQuercus()
  {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (_quercus == null)
        _quercus = new QuercusContext();
    }

    return _quercus;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the script manager.
   */
  public void destroy()
  {
    _quercus.close();
  }

}
```

Signup.php

```
<?php
echo 'This is php in Java with SpringMVC as the controller having a php based view resolver called QuercusView. Awesome!';

?>
```

When I access the resource at /account/signup , I get the following exception

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
        com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext.getCurrentTime(QuercusContext.java:265)
        com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.start(Env.java:1073)
        com.caucho.spring.quercus.QuercusView.renderMergedOutputModel(QuercusView.java:140)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

I'm using Tomcat + openejb + Spring3 as EJB container.

Thanks for helping out.

Please I don't know a lot about the inner workings of SpringMVC and Quercus, but I'm hoping someone can help me with some pointers about how to resolve this.

Thanks for helping out.

**Edit**

The only fishy entry in server startup log is:

```
INFO: OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
[LazyStopWebappClassLoader@5981f6b] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
Dec 7, 2012 4:37:49 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
[LazyStopWebappClassLoader@5981f6b] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type javax.cache.Cache
when weaving type com.caucho.quercus.QuercusContext
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[LazyStopWebappClassLoader@5981f6b] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService
when weaving type com.caucho.quercus.lib.gae.GaeUserService
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Quercus, but by looking at the [source code of QuercusContext](http://massapi.com/source/resin-4.0.20/modules/quercus/src/com/caucho/quercus/QuercusContext.java.html) (line 265) it seems like the timer is not instantiated.

Comment: see _quercusTimer = new QuercusTimer(); (2042)

Comment: yap. But the `NullPointerException` you are getting shows that _quercusTimer is null. Probably the `start()` method never get invoked?

Comment: Okay. I'm thinking this might be the problem. I think QuercusView.java need to be packaged as a jar file and dropped in the classpath. I suspect there's a problem in the order of classloading. What I did at the moment in order to have QuercusView in my classpath is to have the source file in my project package structure. I don't feel good doing it like that.

Comment: I packaged this into a jar and it still didn't work.

Comment: Any exception during server startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work copy https://github.com/PaulWeb/TestJavaPhp
Stanle was right maybe old version but they forgot to add start

```
protected QuercusContext getQuercus()
  {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (this._quercus == null) {
        this._quercus = new QuercusContext();
         this._quercus.start();
      }
    }
    return this._quercus;
  }
```

and if you want to pass from java to php then you have to use  env.setGlobalValue

Comment: Thanks. I got this from nam later on from the Quercus mailing list.